# El primer proyecto Blazor con la demo del contador, no funciona

Tags: c#, blazor

Hace poco preparé mi Visual Studio 2019 Community para crear proyectos Blazor. Al crear un nuevo proyecto, trato de ejecutarlo como lo he visto en varios vídeos en que funciona bien. Pero cada proyecto que genero de prueba, da los mismos errores:

> CS0115 FetchData.OnInitAsync(): No se encontró ningún miembro adecuado
>   para invalidar FetchData.razor Linea 40
>
> CS0234 El tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres Layouts no existe en
>   el espacio de nombres Microsof.AspNetCore.Components (¿falta alguna
>   referencia de ensamblado?) _Imports.razor Línea 3

Veo en vídeos que con todos los pasos cumplidos, este proyecto predeterminado sale funcionando inmediatamente. Soy muy poco experimentado con esta IDE, y más aún con Blazor. Muchas gracias por su ayuda.

Comment: Podes probar de cambiar `OnInitAsync` por `OnInitialized`?

Comment: Con ese cambio, tengo ahora estos errores:

Comment: ¿Cuáles errores? ..

Comment: CS0234 El tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres 'Layouts' no existe en el espacio de nombres 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components' (¿falta alguna referencia de ensamblado?)

Comment: CS0234 El tipo o el nombre del espacio de nombres 'RenderTreeBuilder' no existe en el espacio de nombres 'Microsoft.AspNetCore.Components.RenderTree' (¿falta alguna referencia de ensamblado?)

Comment: Qué versión de .net core tenes?

Comment: CS0508 '__generated__FetchData.OnInitialized()': el tipo de valor devuelto debe ser 'void' para que coincida con el miembro invalidado 'ComponentBase.OnInitialized()'

Comment: Para Blazor es net core 3.0

Comment: Sí, pero .net core 3.0 tiene muchas preview

Comment: La preview 9...

Comment: Gracias Juan Salvador. Efectivamente, había que actualizar a la más reciente versión de .NET Core 3.0, pero además hay que actualizar la IDE Visual Studio 2019. Yo tenía la 16.2.5 y la más reciente con la que funciona, es la 16.3.0. Muchas gracias!!!